# Strange behaviour of connectedComponenentsWithStat in opencv 4.4.0

Tags: opencv, connected-components, python

This is my 8bit image:
[image]

I try to load it with cv2 and split into connected components:

```
seg_r=cv2.imread("seg_r.png",0)
seg_num_labels, seg_labels, seg_stats, seg_centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(seg_r)
print(seg_stats)
```

I get only 2 huge connected components, i.e:

```
[[      0       0    1260    1623   33236]
 [      0       0    1259    1622 2011744]]
```

(I also tried to make black border around image, with no success). Why is this?

Comment: every value == 0 is background, every value > 0 is foreground. If all your pixels with value > 0 are connected, you get 2 labels. Use a binary image!

Comment: please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5), you should use a binary image:

> computes the connected components labeled image of **boolean image**

This means that all pixels with `value==0` are considered as background, while all pixels with `value>0` are foreground.

In your image you probably have all foreground pixels connected, so you end up with only two labels.